# Map attributes not updated properly in Dynamo. New field is added instead.

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using the AWS Java SDK for communicating with DynamoDB. I am trying to do a table update of some properties stored in a map.

Before the update, I have an object that looks like this:

```
{
  "myMap": {
    "innerMap": {}
  },
  "hashKeyName": "hashKeyValue"
}
```

My code looks like this:

```
Table myTable = ...;
myTable.updateItem("hashKeyName", "hashKeyValue", 
        new AttributeUpdate("myMap.innerMap.myKey").addNumeric(100));
```

After this update, my Dynamo object looks like this (notice that the map is still empty):

```
{
  "myMap": {
    "innerMap": {}
  },
  "myMap.innerMap.myKey": 100,
  "hashKeyName": "hashKeyValue"
}
```

Why was `myMap.innerMap.myKey` added as a separate field instead of being correctly set in the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is because using `AttributeUpdate` is considered a legacy operation and the usage of map keys as attribute names is not supported. The correct usage to use an update expression:

```
myTable.updateItem("hashKeyName", "hashKeyValue", 
        "ADD myMap.innerMap.myKey :val", null /* NameMap, see comment */,
        new ValueMap().withNumeric(":val", 100));
```

Notice that there is no name map in the above expression. One might be tempted to do use `ADD #name :val` as an update expression and then provide a name map for `#name => myMap.innerMap.myKey`. In this case, these expressions are **not** equivalent. When a `.` appears in the raw expression, it is treated as a path separator. When `.` appears in a NameMap value, it is not considered a path separator.